# How to delete a row?

Tags: database, ms-access, relational-database

I have a row in MS-accel 2013 which has various dependencies. I deleted them all except the form and report objects, all of which are closed. I still can't delete the row. The extra row is causing the forms and reports to have a row with no data except a (new) auto sequence number and some other data most likely from the old relationship that existed before I made the forms. So now I deleted everything, there are no forms and report. There are just two tables and I deleted any primary keys and relationships. There are no object dependencies. Each form is now standalone yet I still can't delete the row.

Now, I didn't need to delete the reports and forms but I was hoping I would be able to delete the row that way to fix the forms and reports but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom, empty row that you are seeing is a place to enter a new record. It is indicated with a star on the record selector. This will appear on forms when a) the recordsource is not read-only and b) the form's `AllowAdditions` property is yes (the default value for new objects). If you want to hide that row, go to the data tab of the form's property sheet and set `AllowAdditions` to No.

Comment: I'd upvote you if I could, but ya; this was it. It's always the little things that get ya. I swear I've spent 15 hours just trying to fix things like this.